# Custom Force-Directed Symbols in D3 (Tables as nodes)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

Is it possible to create a Force-Directed Graph using your own custom symbols? I know you can make a couple of different symbols (circle, cross, diamond, square, triangle-up, triangle-down) but none of those are complex enough for my purposes. Below is an example of what I want to achieve. Essentially I would like to represent nodes as a table.

[image]

EDIT:

As a starting point I wanted to use Force-Directed Graph example the Mike Bostock posted over [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). Basically, I would like to replace the circles with a table, or possibly any other custom shape that I want.

```
var width = 1000;
var height = 500;
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

d3.json('miserables.json', function(error, graph) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    force
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();

    var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append('line')
        .attr('class', 'link')
        .style('stroke-width', function(d) {
            return Math.sqrt(d.value);
        });

    var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append('circle')
        // <--- I should probably append my custom shape here instead of the circle
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 5)
        .style('fill', function (d) {
            return color(d.group);
        })
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append('title')
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        });

    force.on('tick', function() {
        link.attr('x1', function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
            .attr('y1', function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr('x2', function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr('y2', function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
        });

        node.attr('cx', function (d) {
                return d.x;
        })
            .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT 2:

After many attempts to replace the regular nodes with table, I am still not making a lot of progress. While I am able to create tables and add them to the web page, they are not part of graph. I cannot grab and move the tables around. Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fjotten/L74d474t/2/) and below is the code.

I must be approaching this form the wrong angle. Making a table seems like the thing that fits my needs the best. Making my own SVG elements seems like it would be more complicated than it needs to be.

```
var cols = [
    'Col 1',
    'Col 2'
];

var vals = [
    ['val 1', 'val2'],
    ['val 3', 'val 4']
];

var width = 800;
var height = 500;
var radius = 50;
var color = d3.scale.category20();


//**************************************************//
//*************** Tables as nodes ******************//
//**************************************************//

var arr = [];
var table;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    table = d3.select('#canvas').append('table');
    var thead = table.append('thead');
    var tbody = table.append('tbody');
    thead.append('thead')
        .append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(cols).enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function(col) {
            return col;
        });
    var rows = tbody.append('tbody').selectAll('tr')
        .data(vals, function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter()
        .append('tr');
    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append('td')
        .text(function (d) {
            return d;
        });
    arr.push(table);
}

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(arr)
    .links([])
    .size(width, height)
    .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-200)
    .start();

force.on('tick', function() {
    table.style('top', function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        return d;
    });
});


//**************************************************//
//****************** Old graph *********************//
//**************************************************//

var dataset = {
    nodes: [
        {name: "Adam"},
        {name: "Bob"},
        {name: "Carrie"},
        {name: "Donovan"},
        {name: "Edward"},
        {name: "Felicity"},
        {name: "George"},
        {name: "Hannah"},
        {name: "Iris"},
        {name: "Jerry"}
    ],
    edges: [
        {source: 0, target: 1},
        {source: 0, target: 2},
        {source: 0, target: 3},
        {source: 0, target: 4},
        {source: 1, target: 5},
        {source: 2, target: 5},
        {source: 2, target: 5},
        {source: 3, target: 4},
        {source: 5, target: 8},
        {source: 5, target: 9},
        {source: 6, target: 7},
        {source: 7, target: 8},
        {source: 8, target: 9},
        {source: 8, target: 9}
    ]
};


var force2 = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-3000)
    .linkDistance(200)
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(dataset.nodes)
    .links(dataset.edges)
    .start()


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var edges = svg.selectAll('line')
    .data(dataset.edges)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return 'edge' + i;
    })
    .style('stroke', '#ccc')
    .style('pointer-events', 'none');

var nodes = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(dataset.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr({
        class: 'node'
    })
    .attr('r', radius)
    .style('fill', function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
    })
    .call(force2.drag);

force2.on('tick', function() {
    edges.attr({
        'x1': function (d) {
            return d.source.x;
        },
        'y1': function (d) {
            return d.source.y;
        },
        'x2': function (d) {
            return d.target.x;
        },
        'y2': function (d) {
            return d.target.y;
        }
    });
    nodes.attr({
        'cx': function (d) {
            return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x));
        },
        'cy': function (d) {
            return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you want a table as your node ?

Comment: I guess it could be a table

Comment: instead of creating a circle, append what ever you want. So you could create a table from the data. Add your current code in a fiddle preferably and I can take a look

Comment: I actually do now have any code right now. I am trying to see if D3 is a suitable library for my needs. If/when I have any code I will be sure to add it to my post.

Comment: You can put whatever you want to be a node. Complex [paths](http://www.flaticon.com/) (First link from Googling "SVG path database"), or a table if that will suit your needs. Note that the HTML `<table>` tags aren't available within a SVG so you will have to design your own table, but that is relatively easy. You just have to change what is `append`ed by the force layout.

Comment: I am an idiot and did not include an accurate enough picture. That should be remedied now. Sorry.

Comment: I too am trying something similar. The following link helped me a lot and if I succeed I will post an answer to this. Here's the link : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG has a [group](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Document_Structure#The_g_Element) element that you can use to organize what can be an arbitrarily complex node.

Also, you don't *have* to use an SVG. You can use D3 to manipulate say, the absolute positioning of HTML table elements. In your example, the `tick` updates the cx and cy properties of the circle elements. It could just as easily update the top and left properties of an absolutely positioned table element.

Comment: When you say `You can use D3 to manipulate say, the absolute positioning of HTML table elements.` that would mean that I cannot use the HTML table in conjunction with a force-directed graph, right? Am I correct in assuming that the graph can only handle SVG elements as nodes?

Comment: I hate to be this dense, but do you think you could show something small that shows how you would add a table as a node? 

I am apparently too much of a D3 noob (my 2nd day of D3) to figure it out. All I can do is add table separately from the graph. I will add some code to illustrate this tomorrow. Thanks for your continued help! :)